# What regular expression math double quoted string in a string in javacsript?

Tags: javascript

I have string:

```
"Hello , this is "Hello world". Have a Good day"
```

I need  a `regex` which will return double quoted string only  from string : `"Hello world"`

**What regex will give double quoted string only as output?**

Answer (score 2):

Use escape character:

`"Hello , this is \"Hello world\". Have a Good day"`

Comment: I got my answer. 

Using match():
msg = "Hello , this is "Hello world". Have a Good day";
msg.match(/"([^']+)"/)[1];